# How to Customized Expandable List View?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to customize expandable list view such a way that when user clicks on any group view of that expandable list view then a dialog will be shown but list view will not expand.After selecting some thing from the dialog when user click on `ok` of the dialog the list view will expand and will show data on the base on what selected from dialog.

Can anybody give me any idea how can I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, it should do the trick:

```
mListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                       int groupPosition, long id) {

         boolean shouldIExpandGroups = doSomething();
         if (shouldIExpandGroups)
             return false; // This will cause ListView to expand
         else
          return true; // This will cause ListView to ignore click
    }
});
```